# Не приходят push-уведомления на IOS

Tags: php, ios, push-уведомления

Написан функционал для отправки push-уведомлений для IOS. С локального сервера уведомления приходят, а с сайта нет. Все добавленные выводы указывают на то что уведомление отправлено, но не доходит до устройства. В чем может быть причина?

```php
function replace_unicode_escape_sequence($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UCS-2BE');
  }

  function send_ios_push($message) {
     $sound = 'default';
     $development = true;

     $payload = array();
     $payload["aps"] = array('alert' => $message["body"], 'sound' => $sound);
     $payload = json_encode($payload);
     $payload = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-f]{4})/i', 'replace_unicode_escape_sequence', $payload);

     $apns_url = NULL;
     $apns_cert = NULL;
     $apns_port = 2195;

     if($development) {
        $apns_url = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
        $apns_cert = 'apns-dev.pem';
     } else {
        $apns_url = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
        $apns_cert = 'apns-dev-prod.pem';
     }

     if (file_exists($apns_cert)) 
       echo("cert file exists\n"); 
     else 
       echo("cert file not exists\n");; 
     $success = 0;
     $stream_context = stream_context_create();
     stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apns_cert);
     stream_context_set_option($stream_context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'pass2');

     $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apns_url . ':' . $apns_port, $error, $error_string, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $stream_context);

     $device_tokens =array(
        "ae7c44342eceef645f3baf9f7e1eb2daf383f9341535c8dd5ef7276a29068e8d",
        "8d509c28896865f8640f328f30f15721ed40e41593e40a51e77b91c5b6db17d6"
     );

     foreach($device_tokens as $device) {
       $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $devices)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
       if (fwrite($apns, $apns_message)) {
         $success++;
         echo("sent\n");
       } else {
         echo("failed \n");
       }
     }
     echo("fetch done\n"); 
     socket_close($apns);
     fclose($apns);
     return $success;
  }

  send_ios_push('Hello world');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил, оказывается я сам неправильную кодировку указал в функции replace_unicode_escape_sequence и поэтому сообщения на кириллице не доходили. Для устранения проблемы удалил третий аргумент из функции mb_convert_encoding.